# How can I transfer photos from my Sony wi-fi enabled camera to my iPhones camera roll in the field?

Tags: sony, iphone

I have a Sony 6300, which has wi-fi to transfer photos.

The instruction manual (which is not likely to win any pulitzers) walks through the steps to get the pics into the Sony PlayMemories app. (Bizarrely, it seems to involve scanning a QR code each time you want to make a transfer, but that's neither here nor there.)

So, I'm able to transfer a photo (or all photos taken that day) to the Sony PlayMemories iPhone app. Here's the problem:

**I can't find any way to directly transfer the pictures from the PlayMemories app to my Photos app.**

There's a share button, but it doesn't seem to have a "send to photo roll" extension. I can tweet, email, or message it, but not save it with my other photos. I can obviously hack out a solution that way: email it to myself at full resolution, then save the enclosure, etc. But that's super annoying. Is there some way I'm missing to transfer photos to the camera roll once they're in PlayMemories?  Or is there some other approach entirely that's easier?

Comment: On my Android phone, photos imported to the PlayMemories app are just stored in a separate folder, which I can access from any photo browsing app. I haven't used iPhones for a while, but try looking into whether the Photos app allows browsing folders other than the default one.

Comment: I don't have my camera with me now but last time when I transferred photos, they were saved in PlayMemories Mobile album and were present in Camera Roll too.

Answer (score 3):

The iOS version of PlayMemories is supposed to automatically save imported photos to the iOS camera roll. My best guess for why this isn't happening on your device is that you have not granted the app access to your photos. To give PlayMemories access, go to your iOS Settings > Privacy > Photos > and switch on "PlayMemories Mobile".

From then on it should save them automatically, but I don't know of any way to retroactively save the photos already imported.

Answer (score -1):

They don't show up in the Photos app's first tab. They are saved into an album titled `PlayMemories Mobile`. Find it in the Photos app -> Albums tab.

Comment: Actually, it does. I encountered the exact same problem and then I found them in an obscure album, they don't end up in the "camera roll" at all. Which is what OP asked.

Comment: Care to explain further in your answer?